Как будет правильно сделать синхронизацию с базой данных и тг ботом + как сделать так, чтобы при броске кости сканировался результат?
import telebot
import sqlite3
from asyncio import __all__
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

database = sqlite3.connect("result.db")

cur = database.cursor()

api = "token"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(api)

name_of_game = 'name' #Ввести название игры

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,  f'''Привет! 
Ты попал в игру {name_of_game}

Правила просты. ✅

1. Не списывать, наш бот имеет доступ к просмотру Ваших действий вне бота (Спец. API телеграм).  

2.  Не ломать бота. Если вы сломаете бота ( от огромного кол-ва спама) вы будете дисквалифицированы из игры 

3. Вносить настоящую информацию. В нашем боте имеется база данных, с помощью которой мы узнаем все результаты игры.''')

    bot.reply_to(message, "Чтобы начать игру нужно ознакомиться с командами, /help ")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, '''Перечень команд: 
    
/start - Команда для запуска бота 
/help - Команда для списка команд.
/sg - Команда для начала игры
    ''')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['sg'])
def sg(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Великолепно, приступим... Начнем с знакомства! Как тебя зовут и твой класс (Пример: Иванов Иван 7 О)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)

def process_name_step(message):
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Приятно познакомиться твое имя и класс:, {name}!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start_game'])
def quiz(message):
    #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну давай, теперь бросай кубик ( используй эмодзи  )')
    #bot.send_dice(chat_id="", emoji='')
    result: Message = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id)
    print(result.dice.value)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
database.close()


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у меня вписанная информация от пользователя, прямиком падала в базу данных, также нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь бросал кость и по данным кости должен "Пойти на свой ход".
